# Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: html5, bootstrap, angular, modal

En mi component.html. Estoy intentando crear un botón que muestre el texto de cada publicación con modal pero cuando le pongo el id con cada publicación me aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo

```
<div *ngIf="publication.user._id == identity._id">
    <button class="btn btn-danger"  data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal{{publication._id}}">
        <fa-icon icon="trash"></fa-icon>
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{publication._id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Borrar Publicacion</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Estas seguro de que quieres borrar la publicacion?</p>
                <p>{{publication.text}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

El problema parece ser cuando le coloco el id al modal con el id de la publicación. Pero si no lo coloco solo me aparece la de la primera publicación.

Comment: Prueba con `[attr.data-target]="'#tuId"`

Comment: Ahora aparece Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 5 in [#myId{{publication._id}}]

Comment: La sintaxis debería ser `[attr.data-target]="'#' + id"`, ya que no se pueden utilizar parentésis en este caso

Comment: Lo puse `[attr.data-target]="'#' + publication._id"` en el button y al modal `id="publication._id"`. Asi esta bien la sintaxis? Por que ahora me aparece `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#5cc067ec2bc893221479f3a7' is not a valid selector`

Comment: No, en el modal debería ir con las llaves correspondientes

Comment: Como quedaria en este caso? `id="{{publication._id}}"` Asi?

Comment: Exactamente.. Prueba y me comentas

Comment: Sigue apareciendo `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#5cc067ec2bc893221479f3a7' is not a valid selector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En angular las variables para los atributos se concatenan sin las llaves {{}}.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" [attr.data-toggle]="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#myModal'+publication._id">
```

Luego al id si se lo concatenas con las llaves {{}}.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{publication._id}}" ... >
```